# Does Anyone Have Any Integrals With Unconventional Substitutions?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Soft question:

I recently discovered Weierstrass substitutions (tangent half-angle, $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2}$)) and became intrigued with substitutions arising from unit circle re-parametrization. So I did some more research and found some weird substitutions for indefinite integrals like
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{1+\csc^2x}\,dx$$
I'm wondering if anyone wants to share any amusing/weird/unconventional substitutions for relatively simple integrals?

Comment: Read the posts of the user Quanto, here on MSE. They are very good at finding efficient and nonobvious substitutions

Comment: What "weird" substitution did you use for the integral of your example? a "non-weird" one is $y=\sin x.$ (See [Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can have no single good answer, and it could lead to the posting of everyone's favourite change of integration variable.

Comment: @FShrike, I am new to MSE. How to find a user? Or to send him a message?

Comment: I don’t think it’s appropriate for me to post a link but you can just type a name in the MSE browser, this picks up the more famous users

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found an interesting indefinite integral: $$\int{\frac{x^2+2\cos x-1}{(1+x^2)\sin x-2x}dx}$$For there are both $x$,$\sin x and \cos x$ in the integral,I think your Weierstrass substitutions may be invalid.

Here is the answer：
Let $p=x\cos \frac{x}{2}-\sin \frac{x}{2}$ and $q=x\sin \frac{x}{2}-\cos \frac{x}{2}$

Why do we have so strange p and q？In fact we have the factorization that $2pq=(1+x^2)\sin x-2x$ and $2(p\ dq-q\ dp)=(x^2+2\cos x-1)\ dx$,and now we have the  result:$$\int{\frac{x^2+2\cos x-1}{(1+x^2)\sin x-2x}dx}=\int\frac{p\ dq-q\ dp}{pq}=log\frac{q}{p}+C=log(x\tan (\frac{x}{2})-1)-log(x-\tan \frac{x}{2})+C$$